# How to echo user select optionset from ChoiceSet using messageBack or imBack?

Tags: json, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am trying to echo the user selected option from given set of user rating drop down using messageBack or imBack (whichever is possible). Since, I am only able to add a static text as value in messageBack value field

```
"actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "OK",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "imBack",
          "value": "User selected option"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Is there a way that I can get the value from choiceset and show is using messageBack on MS Teams?

You can refer to complete JSON here:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "color": "Accent",
      "text": "Rate your experience!"
    },
    {

      "type": "TextBlock",
      "separator": true,
      "text": "Please rate your experience! Your feedback is very appreciated and will help improve your experience in the future. ",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "id": "CompactSelect",
      "label": "What color do you want? (compact)",
      "style": "compact",
      "isRequired": true,
      "errorMessage": "This is a required input",
      "placeholder": "Please choose",
      "choices": [
        {
          "title": "⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐",
          "value": "⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐"

        },
        {
          "title": "⭐⭐⭐⭐",
          "value": "⭐⭐⭐⭐"
        },
        {
          "title": "⭐⭐⭐",
          "value": "⭐⭐⭐"

        },
        {
          "title": "⭐⭐",
          "value": "⭐⭐"

        },
        {
          "title": "⭐",
          "value": "⭐"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "OK",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "imBack",
          "value": "User selected option"
        }
      }
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: I tested your Adaptive Card json, You can try to set the Id for input choices and check if value for bot context is defined what you selected or not, try to echo the value using submit action

Comment: can you share the code for same? I am new to this adaptive card and botframework so it gets difficult sometimes to understand the verbal solutions.

Answer (score 2):

@user30 - Could you please check this Code?

```
var InputChoices = new List<AdaptiveChoice> {
          new AdaptiveChoice() { Title = "Red",
            Value = "Red" },
        new AdaptiveChoice() { Title = "Green",
            Value = "Green" },
  new AdaptiveChoice() { Title = "White",
            Value = "White" },
  new AdaptiveChoice() { Title = "Black",
            Value = "Black" }
   };
 return new AdaptiveCard()
      {
        Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                {
 new AdaptiveColumnSet()
                    {
                        Columns=new List<AdaptiveColumn>()
                        {
                            new AdaptiveColumn()
                            {
                                Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                {
                                    new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                    {
                                        Text="Colors",
                                        Id="colorCodeId",
                                        Spacing=AdaptiveSpacing.None,
                                        Wrap=true
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            new AdaptiveColumn()
                            {
                                Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                {
                                    new AdaptiveChoiceSetInput()
                                    {
                                        Id="colorCodeId",
                                        Spacing=AdaptiveSpacing.None,
                                        Choices=new List<AdaptiveChoice>(InputChoices),
                                        Style=AdaptiveChoiceInputStyle.Compact
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
        Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
                {
                    new AdaptiveSubmitAction
                    {
                        Type = AdaptiveSubmitAction.TypeName,
                        Title = "Submit"
                 },
                },
      }
```