# Use AdaptiveCard form value of Input.Choiceset as a messageback on Submit button

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card which displays a list of pipelines in a choice set, I want to use the value of the selected pipelines as a messageback to teams on selecting the submit button. How can I access the value of the id of Input.Choiceset?

This is the snippet for Submit Action -

```
    "actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Execute",
        "data": {
            "msteams": {
                "type": "messageBack",
                "text": "" (Choiceset value here)
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This is the Choiceset snippet -

```
    {
        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
        "id": "pipelineSelect",
        "choices": "${list}",
        "placeholder": "pipelines"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent answer to a similar question that might help. Check out [How to echo user select optionset from ChoiceSet using messageBack or imBack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462083/how-to-echo-user-select-optionset-from-choiceset-using-messageback-or-imback) . In addition, it might help to see more info on the [CardAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/cardaction?view=botbuilder-ts-3.0) class, as well as [this blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) - see the "Card Action in Teams" section which even describes some more advanced messageBack options.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462083/how-to-echo-user-select-optionset-from-choiceset-using-messageback-or-imback) the question is similar to mine, but the question has not been answered suitably as they are looking into the validation from the source code of the bot. I am looking for echoing the user-selected value back to the bot with "msteams": "messageBack" functionality on Submit.

Comment: have you tested what actually comes back to your bot? The value should be in there, I think, just not in your "text" field - it should come back in the "data" payload somewhere. Are you running locally with ngrok? If so, check the local proxy page (http://localhost:4040) to see the payload as it's sent through - it's very helpful to see that to understand what's 'on the wire'

Comment: Yes, I have checked and the user input is coming back in the data payload on submit, as a per the ID specified. I am hosting the bot on AWS Lambda and have an API Gateway as an endpoint. I just want to use that value in messageBack instead of processing it from the payload.

Comment: You will receive the input.choiceset value in the data only this is by design. When you submit he adaptive card value you can desterilize the data json and send the input.choice set value to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yeah, dynamically assigning user values has still not been implemented for Adaptive Cards and is part of their roadmap.